# How do I calculate bandwidth consumption of 700 users

Tags: networking, bandwidth, calculator

Id like to know how to properly calculate the consumption of user downloads in a given specified bandwidth.

Say, I have 700 users which will simultaneously download an image with file size (300KB).
My server bandwidth capacity is 100MB.

How many MB does 700 users will consume on my 100MB server bandwidth?

Comment: did you mean 100MB/s?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get the terms right. Bandwidth always refers to an amount of data per unit of time that can be transmitted over a channel. So, for example, Internet connections are offered with 50 MBit/s.

Your server has a *traffic* plan, which just gives you an amount of data per time frame, independent of the server's actual bandwidth. You have 100 MB per month, I suppose. The server could still be connected to the Internet with a bandwidth of 1 Gb/s.

Now, you have *n* users downloading an image with size *s*. What is the total size downloaded by these users? It's very simple: *n × s*. Fill in the numbers and you will know.

Note that 100 MB of traffic is really not much for a server. Consider changing your data plan—you'll easily reach that limit soon.